# How to receive notifications from printer/print spooler for every page while printing Excel sheets?

Tags: excel, printing, spooler

I've written an Excel add-in in C#.NET. When ever the user opens and Excel workbook and give a print on a worksheet, the excel does the print. There is only one notification that is raised by the excel, that is the AppEvents.Workbbok_BeforePrint() event. After that there is no events generated for each page before the page is printed.

I've analysed ways to receive notification from excel side. But could not find one. 
Then i tried the option to receive notifications from the printer/print spooler. 
How can i get notification from the printer/print spooler, so that i receive notification for every page that is printed.

Please help me out in this.

Thanks and Regards,
Sundareswaran Senthilvel

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult to do, especially if there aren't a lot of pages in the print job. It's probably more work than it's worth. :)

You can do it, however, using the WinAPI functions [EnumJobs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162625%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [GetJob](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144894%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Call [OpenPrinter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162751%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to get a printer handle.

Call [GetPrinter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144911%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) with level 2 to find out the number of jobs.

Call [EnumJobs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162625%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). Examine the JOB_INFO_1, JOB_INFO_2, or JOB_INFO_3 (depending on what information you asked for - links on the other pages above to these structures and what they tell you) until you find the print job from Excel.

Call [GetJob](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144894%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) using that JobID to get information on the current status of the print operation.

Comment: Hi Ken, Thanks for your reply. i have come across .NET PrintDocument class where we can set the handlers for the event.